# Not able to open model popup from _layout page in another view page(ex: login page)

Tags: popup

In my Core 6.0 project I am trying to load a modal popup on login page from _Layout.cshtml but nothing happens. On click of Show Popup button. I am trying to display different html page in a single modal popup on clicking different button from different page. Below is code-

Login page:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="showbtn">add new user</button>
 <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-left: 575px">
        <form asp-action="Login">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Username" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:auto">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <a asp-action="ForgotPassword" >Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

User details page:

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="addbtn">Add Mobile Number</button>
_layout page:
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>

<div class="modal fade" id='myModal'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Show Status</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible?

I am trying to display different html page in a single modal popup on clicking different button from different page.